# Is there cross domain policy in a UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, cross-domain-policy

I am loading html into a UIWebView from iOS local file system.
That HTML page is requesting json data on our server.

I can fetch the json data, so the question is, is there no cross domain policy in a UIWebView, or am I missing out something here?

Comment: That's what makes it so useful :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's the same as desktop Safari:

- If you're loading a local (file) url in a UIWebView then there are no cross domain restrictions
- If you're loading external urls they'll be limited to that domain, unless the site has correct Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers set.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your first point? I'm curious to find it documented somewhere. Cheers